# Clear all OSX defaults

Tags: macos, command-line

How can I clear all of the defaults set in OSX from the command line and start fresh I can't seem to run something like defaults delete with an all flag

Comment: What do you mean all of the osx defaults?

Answer (score 0):

To restore user defaults you could delete all the .plist files in the various ~/Library/Preferences/

Some apps also store preference plists in ~/Library/Application\ Support/.

There's also another Preferences and Application\ Support folder in /Library, though those are system files (or apps installed with admin privileges)